# How to get array from nsdisctionary swift

Tags: json, swift, nsdictionary

I have below json object. i am parsing json and storing this as disctionary. now i want to get these array from disctionary but when i am using objectForKey("upcomingAppointments") it given me nothing

```
{
  "upcomingAppointments": [],
  "upcomingFollowUps": [],
  "followUps": []
}
```

[image: DISCTIONARY]

Comment: If you log your json object, can you see it  being full and correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var dictionary = //NSDictionary from somewhere...

if let upcomingAppointments = dictionary["upcomingAppointments"] as? NSArray {
    //Process your appointments here.
}

//Same goes for other such json fields.
```